# Apache as proxy not working for all sites

Tags: facebook, apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

can somebody tell me why

```
ProxyPass /melonfire/ http://www.melonfire.com/
```

can work by accessing http://localhost/melonfire/ but

```
ProxyPass /facebook/ http://www.facebook.com/
```

is redirectig the browser to http://www.facebook.com/

Why? How could I make these redirections stop?